# Count # of time basic operation is executed

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I've been given this algorithm to compute the sum of the n first cubes:

```
s(n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return 1 
  } else {
    return s(n - 1) + n * n * n
  }
}
```

To count the number of times the basic operation is executed I'm asked to use the following recurrence relation: `T(1) = 0` and `T(n) = T(n - 1) + 2`

Can someone explain to me why the relation looks like this, more precisely: Where does the number 2 comes from?

If `n = 2`, in my opinion, `T(2) = 1` since the multiplication is only executed once, but according to the formula `T(2) = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity here is the complexity of running the multiplication operation, which happens twice at each iteration due to `n * n * n`. Also note that `T(2) = 2`:

```
T(2) = T(1) + 2
     = 0    + 2
     = 2
```

In general this algorithm's complexity is `O(2n)` which is equivalent to `O(n)`, and the algorithm can be written as a simple for loop:

```
s(n):
    r := 0
    for i := 1 to n
        r := r + i * i * i
    return r
```

Comment: Note that T(0) is not defined but T(3) = 4.

The reason why its +2 is because 2 operations is need to multiplicate 3 numbers?

Comment: Sorry I read it as `T(0) = 0`, but the multiplication happens twice at each level, `n * n * n` that's two multiplications not one, so `T(3) = T(2) + 2 = T(1) + 2 + 2 = 4`.